# How do I create a new excel sheet dynamically using python?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to create a excel sheet which doesnt exist till now dynamically on runtime.
I dont want to add sheets in excel sheet but I want to create a whole new excel file with the name of a random unique id created at runtime.
Is there any chance I can do that using openpyxl or any other library in python.
Your any help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Yes you can use openpyxl. Pandas can also be a good choice. See for example https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely!

First you need the required libraries. Personally, I've use the following combination libraries - and in my experience, they work exactly as expected.

1. [Pandas](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/): `pip install pandas`
2. [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.org/project/XlsxWriter/): `pip install XlsxWriter`
3. [Xlrd](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/) (optional - used for reading in excel files): `pip install xlrd`

Once you have them installed, you can adapt the following code snippet ([taken from XlsxWriter's docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html)) to your requirements.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from the data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Comment: Why bother with Pandas just to create an XLSX file?